# What use are confirms/commits if the broker will simply drop a message off a queue & then confirm?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to build a system with strong guarantees that each message passed into a queue will be reached by the consumer. However transactional commits and seem to only confirm that the broker received the message, it still may have evicted a message to make space for the new message.

What is the best way to get a strong guarantee that every message will be picked up and processed?

Comment: "it still may have evicted a message to make space for the new message" - what makes you say that? Are you using queues with a max length or size set?

Comment: Yes we have a maximum size for queue length, as well as a maximum size on our vhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are limiting the maximum queue length, I recommend upgrading to version `3.7.X` which introduced a feature that will return a `basic.nack` message to the publisher if the queue length is reached. Set `overflow` to `reject-publish`.

Read about it here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html